# Facebook real time update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook real time updates in my rails app. 
I added realtime update fields for "user" and "email" object in facebook settings page with the following parameters:

```
    Object: user
    Fields: email, likes
    Callback: http://fb-realtime-test.herokuapp.com/facebook/subscription
    Verify Token: stringToken
```

I can also able to get a subscriptions for the fields i subscribed.

The URL 
https://graph.facebook.com/141213822708267/subscriptions?access_token=141213822708267|-drf6Izviu3BSJ1YgU-Dx5Wi0GY&method=get

Returns

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "object": "user",
         "callback_url": "http://fb-realtime-test.herokuapp.com/facebook/subscription",
         "fields": [
            "email",
            "likes"
         ],
         "active": true
      }
   ]
}
```

I also added permission for "**user_likes**" and "**email**" when the user login.
But i am not able to see the POST call from Facebook if any likes or email is modified.

Please guide me what i am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I am not able to get POST callback from facebook because i hosted my rails app n heroku. With Heroku it limits for single process thus i got only GET from facebook but not POST. Heroku blocks other processes with single dyno. To support that we need to get two dynos to get post callback from facebook.